# Search Bar in a Navigation Item collapses and gets stuck under status bar upon navigation pop, on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios11

I am using the new iOS 11 [`searchContoller`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller) property of a `UINavigationItem`. I am running iOS 11.0 GM build.

When I perform a push segue whilst the search controller is active, it works fine. When I subsequently pop back, the search bar is collapsed and squashed up in the status bar. I cannot then cancel the search, or edit the search text.

See the following sequence of images:

[image: Initial table state][image: Filtered table with search][image: Collapsed search bar on pop]

The final image is showing the appearing of the table during the pop segue to return from a presented view controller back to the table with the search bar. Strangely, this doesn't *always* happen. It happens 90% of the time, but sometimes it behaves fine. I haven't yet worked out what I am doing differently to make it work. Once the search bar is squashed, I have to force close the app to get back to a sensible state.

The code which sets up the search controller is pretty standard. The relevant bit of `viewDidLoad()` is as follows:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Your Library"
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

// We will manage the clearing of selections ourselves.
clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

// Some search bar styles are slightly different on iOS 11
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationController!.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
else {
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor!
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.height), animated: false)
}
```

I've also noticed this issue in Apple's Messages app (see screenshot below), along with Settings, Notes and Mail, so presumably this is an iOS 11 bug.

[image: Messages app search bar squashed on pop]

This only seems to happen when using smaller than default Text Size in Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Larger Text, and only seems to happen on a physical device (haven't reproduced it in the simulator). In `viewDidAppear`, `searchController.searchBar.frame.height` is equal to `0` (but not in `viewDidDisappear`, not `viewWillAppear`). The only workaround I have so far is:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *), searchController.searchBar.frame.height == 0 {
        navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false
    }

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Is there a better way to get around this problem?

Comment: Having similar issues on my end..

Comment: I've now raised a bug report with Apple...

Comment: Send me the radar so I'll promote it

Comment: The URL of the bug report I filed is https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=34459254
I don't know if that's accessible to other users. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Just got an email notifying me that the bug report is closed, as it is a duplicate of 33893656

Comment: Lets hope it'll get fixed at 11.1

Answer (score 2):

This bug can be reproduced in iOS 11.1:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;
    }
}
```

Avoiding mutate navigationItem on VC lifecycle events, fixed problem for me