# TableView first cell hidden under search bar when returning to view

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have some weird behaviour on a TableView and hope someone could help me out.

I have a TableView with a searchbar in the navigation. The cells lead to a detail view. Whenever I search in the TableView and then hit a result cell to go to the detail view, on returning from the detail view to the TableView the first cell disappears underneath the opened search bar.

Searching:

[image: Searching]

On selecting the item (detail view) and then returning (using the nav bar) the first cell is hidden under the search bar:

[image: Returning]

Some things to note:

- If I print the contentInset on returning it gives -44 (1 cell hidden, like in the pic). I'm unable to set the contentInset back to 0.0 (or anything else for that matter) as it doesn't seem to change anything.

```swift
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
print(tableView.contentOffset.y)

// -44.0
```

If the first cell is hidden and I hide the search bar by pushing the table down and then up again, the problem automatically disappears and the ContentInset restores to 0.0.

**UPDATE**: I found that the view restores itself as well after returning the app from the background:

[image]

I can't however reproduce that in code. I've tried:

```swift
view.setNeedsLayout()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I guess it is because of scrollview insets. Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335497/uisearchbar-on-uitableview-strange-offset-issue

Comment: There are other ways to solve it but above seems simplest one.

Comment: How have you implemented your tableView? Are you using a `UITableViewController` or manually adding a `UITableView`?

Comment: @Rahul: that doesn't seem to be the same issue as mine. I already tried toggling the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`.

Comment: @RichAppz `UITableViewController`. I add the search bar programmatically in the `viewDidLoad`. I have the same implementation in other views as well where it doesn't have the same error, maybe it's the detail view that's causing it.

Comment: try adding this: `tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = true` - if it solves the problem I will add as answer.

Comment: @RichAppz didn't help either. Could it be due to something I'm doing in the detail view? Other similar view don't have this issue. The detail view in question plays with height constraints to scale images based on scroll position for example, though I don't see what the detail view has to do with its parent.

Comment: @Tum are you doing anything to the navigationbar or top layout in the detail viewcontroller? Ìt would help if you press the view debugger and show us what how to the layout looks with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I set `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`, which caused the bug. See the answer on this post: [Search Bar in a Navigation Item collapses and gets stuck under status bar upon navigation pop, on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239530/search-bar-in-a-navigation-item-collapses-and-gets-stuck-under-status-bar-upon-n).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Put dismiss(animated: true) in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)